# Is it possible to perform split payment in bitpay

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, bitcoin-core

Hi all coming to the question am using bitpay payment in my project..Is there any possible to perform split payment using bitpay

For example am performing bitpay payment for 100 usd for one wallet address
it should be split(50+50) and sent to two wallets 50USD for one address and another 50 USD for second address

Is it possible to perform in bitpay kindly help me if you know the way to do

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to receive to two addresses or send from two different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did it few minutes ago.

After I sent the first amount from wallet A I got the message that the invoice is not paid completely and that X BTC is left.
Then I send the left BTCs from Wallet B to the address and now I must wait for verification of the transactions.

But seems to be working :-)